# VMWare - Start guest in full screen (bat file or by configuration)

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player, fullscreen

The question is simple, and the Title says it all.
I want to launch my guest VM in full-screen with a bat file, or with a configuration setting (whatever possible).

Tried some solution that I found online, but they didn't really work. Like the "-X" switch, will start the guest like I'd start it by hand.

Host OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1 HomePremium

Answer (score 0):

A Windows shortcut (.lnk) has a few properties, including "Run: [Normal Window|Minimized|Maximized]". You can easily check how this works by creating a shortcut to a .txt file. Set it to open Maximized, and Notepad will open full screen.

You can then use `Start shortcut.lnk` to start the target of the shortcut (e.g. the VM) from a bat file.